# How to integrate openshift to Google SMTP (Gmail) to send mails using PHP?

Tags: openshift

I am doing programming in PHP in Eclipse. Now I want to send mails from openshift through gmail. Please suggest me how to do. I went through articles but it is showing that we have to do programming in j2EE for configuring that. But I do only PHP programming.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably first try to take a look at php `mail()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.phphttp://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and see how that works.

You can also use libraries/frameworks that will do most of the work for you, for instance, using [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html):

```php
// Include the library
require_once('lib/swift_required.php');

// Setup your account and provider
// For Gmail: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287?hl=en
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.google.com', 465, 'ssl')
  ->setUsername('user@gmail.com')
  ->setPassword('password');

// Create the mailer instance
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Prepare the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('sender@whatever.com' => 'Sender Name'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@whatever.com' => 'Receiver Name'))
  ->setBody('Email body');

// Use the mailer instance to send the message
$result = $mailer->send($message);
```

You can find Gmail SMTP server details here: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/13287?hl=en

Also note that it's not relevant what editor/IDE you are using, and that's probably what's causing you not being able to find relevant results on your search.